# Creating 2 panels and 2 hlines with facet_grid & ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

this is my second try to ask a question. I hope this time I can give you a reproducible example.

I have a data.frame with the variables DIS and Date. I would like to plot the data.frame with ggplot2. Date on the x-axis, DIS on the y-axis.

I would like to plot it in two panels but with the same scale on the y-axis.

Panel 1: 1Q1 until 4Q4.
Panel 2: P1 until P3.
Furthermore, I would like to plot 4 horizontal lines:

lower limit of a control group (should be the same in Panel 1 and Panel 2)
upper limit of a control group (should be the same in Panel 1 and Panel 2)
mean of DIS for Panel 1 (should be visible only in Panel 1)
mean of DIS for Panel 2 (should be visible only in Panel 2)
I tried to use face_grid and geom_hline but as you can see, I get 19 panels and the horizontal lines are visible at all panels.

```
DIS=c(0.1120, 0.1104, 0.3794, 0.3983, 0.3175, 0.2275, 0.2171, 0.1973, 0.2499, 0.1819, 0.2613, 0.2302, 0.3795, 0.2406, 0.2486, 0.2464, 0.1143, 0.2685, 0.2447)
    Date=c("1Q1","1Q2","1Q3","1Q4","2Q1","2Q2","2Q3","2Q4","3Q1","3Q2","3Q3","3Q4","4Q1","4Q2","4Q3","4Q4","P1","P2", "P3" )

Bush <- data.frame(Date, DIS)

require (ggplot2)

ggplot(Bush, aes(x = Date, y = DIS))+
  geom_point(shape=1)+
  ylim(0,0.5)+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0.07), linetype="dotted")+ #that's the lower limit of the control group
  geom_hline(yintercept=0.19, linetype="dotted")+ # that's the upper limit of the control group
  geom_hline(yintercept=mean(Bush$DIS[1:16]), colour="blue")+ # that's the mean of the values from 1Q1 to 4Q4 - it should only range from 1Q1 until 4Q4 on the x-axis
  geom_hline(yintercept=mean(Bush$DIS[17:19]), colour="blue")+ # that's the mean of the values from P1 to P3 - it should only range from P1 to P3 on the x-axis
  facet_grid(.~ Date, scales="free_x") # it should be grouped in two panels - 1st from 1Q1 to 4Q4, 2nd from P1 to P3
```

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: I'm sure lots of people would love to help, but you haven't provided nearly enough of the right information. You say `facet_grid` "doesn't work" but you have not included what you've tried, or explained _how_ it didn't work. Also, you code isn't reproducible (i.e. we can't simply copy+paste it on our computers to see exactly what the problem is). Fix those issues in your question, and I'm sure you'll get a solution very quickly.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to solve it that way: 
ggplot(Bush, aes(x = Date, y = DIS, group=periods))+
  geom_point(shape=1)+
  ylim(0,0.5)+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0.07), linetype="dotted")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0.19, linetype="dotted")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=mean(Bush$DIS[1:16]), colour="blue")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=mean(Bush$DIS[17:19]), colour="blue")+
  facet_grid(.~ Date, scales="free_x")</end code>

Comment: periodQ  <- c("1Q1", "1Q2", "1Q3", "1Q4", "2Q1", "2Q2", "2Q3", "2Q4", "3Q1", "3Q2", "3Q3", "3Q4", "4Q1", "4Q2", "4Q3", "4Q4")
periodP  <- c("P1", "P2", "P3")
periods = c(rep("Quartale", length (periodQ)), rep("Perioden", length(periodP)))
ggplot(Bush, aes(x = Date, y = DIS, group=periods))+
  geom_point(shape=1)+
  ylim(0,0.5)+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0.07), linetype="dotted")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0.19, linetype="dotted")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=mean(Bush$DIS[1:16]), colour="blue")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=mean(Bush$DIS[17:19]), colour="blue")+
  facet_grid(.~ group, scales="free_x")

Comment: Then I tried to group it (see above). But it does not work: "Error in layout_base(data, cols, drop = drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting" I Want to groups of panels - 1st: Quaters (1Q1 until 4Q4) and 2nd Periods (P1 until P3)

Comment: (1) Never put code in the comments. There is a reason you are allowed to edit your question. (2) We can't help, because you didn't do as I suggested and provide a _reproducible_ example.

Comment: @1: Sorry! @2: Ok, then I will try to post a new question with a reproducible example. And thank you for your patience!!! I really appreciate that!

Comment: NO! **Edit** this question! If you post a new one, folks will quickly close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are faceting on your x variable. If you want different faceting behavior you need to create a specific variable that matches the behavior you want to see:

```
Bush$grp <- rep(c('a','b'),times = c(16,3))
```

So I've created a new variable that groups the observations in the way you seem to want them to appear together in panels. Then you just facet on that variable:

```
facet_grid(.~ grp, scales="free_x")
```

To make the horizontal lines appear in separate panels, the strategy is the same. (It's always the same, that's the trick with ggplot!) You make a data frame, with a variable that describes where everything goes:

```
mean_df <- data.frame(grp = c('a','b'),
                      yint = with(Bush,c(mean(DIS[1:16]),mean(DIS[17:19]))))
```

and then pass that data frame to `geom_hline` and map `yintercept` to `yint`:

```
geom_hline(data = mean_df,aes(yintercept = yint),colour = "blue")
```

Comment: Thank you. That works fine! Just one last question: how can I change the interval of the x-axis, so that a and b are not the same size. P1 to P3 should be as big as 1Q1 to 1Q3.

Comment: ok, I found the answer on my own - I use scales="free" and space="free"